# Tkinter Canvas postscript saves as 1x1

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am making trying to make a chess game using Canvas. But when i try to get the image that i made using canvas, it returns a 1x1 image.

Heres the code that i am using

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, EpsImagePlugin
import io

EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary = r'gs\bin\gswin64c.exe'

def interpret(c, p, x, y):
    path = "images/" + c + '/' + c[0] + p + ".png"

    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("1200x1200")
    canvas= Canvas(win, width= 1200, height=1200)
    canvas.pack()
    table = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/table.png"))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=table)
    wp = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    canvas.create_image((150 * x) - 150, (150 * y) - 150,anchor=NW,image=wp)

    postscript = canvas.postscript(colormode='color')
    
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(postscript.encode('utf-8')))
    img.show()      
    
interpret('black', 'p', 4, 5)
```

I tried saving it as an eps and converting it to a PNG, but still doesnt work. I expected that it saved as a 1200x1200 (table.png resolution) PNG file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that the canvas hasn't had a chance to render yet so tkinter doesn't know the size of the widget, defaulting to its current 1x1 size.

From the official tcl/tk documentation on the `postscript` method:

> If the canvas is freshly created it may still have its initial size of 1x1 pixel so nothing will appear in the Postscript. **To get around this problem either invoke the update command to wait for the canvas window to reach its final size, or else use the -width and -height options to specify the area of the canvas to print.**

Comment: There is a problem, since the image is 1200x1200, and my screen is 1920x1080, the postscript image get cutted. How do i fix that?

Comment: @spookyss: have you tried what the above answer suggests, and use the `width` and `height` options to the `postscript` method?